# Insert 2 PDF pages presentation per Book page, keeping the header/footer style of the book

Tags: pdf, books

I would like to insert a presentation pdf (which contains several pages - Landscape format) in my report (book Style) keeping the header and footer of the report, 2 slides per pages.

I am wondering if they are some specific packages for that.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to export PDF presentation into separate pictures (one page into one picture). Then you can embed pictures into your report keeping the layout.

Comment: I see. Is there an automatic simple way for doing it please ?

Comment: I would use Adobe Acrobat Pro, but there are free, even online converters, just type something like "pdf to jpg" in google.

Comment: Later you can manipulate JPGs with your favorite software (not necessary one-by-one). Embedding them into LaTeX is also easy. Any doubts?

Comment: If they are no other solutions - well, I count it as complete. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wait! I see this solution as simple, but perhaps someone can provide better way. I didn't want to confuse you. Now I see, I shouldn't say "easiest". Maybe you can unaccept my answer?

Comment: alright, done according to your request. Maybe they are some other solutions.

Comment: Have you tried to do it already? 1step: convert PDF document into set of pictures (few clicks); 2step: modify pictures and pictures' names as a set in software that you know (few clicks); 3step: insert pictures into your LaTeX document (few lines to type and few clicks). The more you prepare images outside LaTeX, the easier and quicker this job will be. You don't have to do it one-by-one. You can automate it, but this depends on software that you use. For example, you don't need to write "\includegraphics{s_01.jpg} ... \includegraphics{s_22.jpg}", you can use regular expressions and macros.

Comment: Yes I did it in your way. I am just curious to know if they are actually other solutions, you see.

Comment: Nice to hear, that my answer was helpful:) From my experience, crucial thing is to use efficient tools. For example, for editing images use image editor, for repetitive modification of images use batch-processing plugin or another app, for inserting many similar lines into LaTeX code use proper text editor with macros and regexp. And if you are happy with final effects, don't waste time for doing the same thing in different way only because you can. Seriously, don't waste your time, it's not worth doing.